# Renewal JWT token on Kong API Gateway OSS

Tags: jwt, api-gateway, kong, renewal

I Have a microservice with JWT plugin on Kong OSS. And i have this issue, when my bearer token JWT expires, how i can revew or create another token automatically?. Exists any  JWT Signer plugin or JWT renewal for Kong OSS?
Greetings.Somebody have any ideas of solve this question?. Any experience of this issue?

Comment: I think it depends solely on your front-end application. When Kong returns 401 indicating that the token is expired, catch that error and craft a new JWT token.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. Any suggestions for a Kong OSS Plugin for generate JWT token bearer for Fron-tend application?